# MySQL select multi conditions

Tags: php, mysql

As beginner I have been struggling to find a solution to the following situation:

I have 3 tables:

```
Table 1: CITIES 
id|city
1|London
2|Paris


Table 2: CATEGORIES 
id|category
1|category1
2|category2

Table 3: PRODUCTS 
id|city|category|name|keyword
1|1|1|product1|keyword1
2|1|1|product2|keyword2
```

Now I need help to mysql select to display for search results, something like this:

```
<?php
$keyword = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z]#', '', $_GET['keyword']);
$city = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['city']);
$category = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['category']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '$category' AND city = '$city' AND keyword LIKE '$keyword'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$category = $row['category'];
$city = $row['city'];
}
?>
```

my url is: `search.php?keyword=keyword&category=1&city=1`
this is working fine but if any of arguments is missing, then is displaying 0 results

```
sample: search.php?keyword=&category=&city=1
```

Comment: what if you use OR instead of AND ?

Comment: use OR instead of AND. AND expects all parameters to be in place

Comment: Please edit your question to show sample data.  The data structure doesn't make sense.  You have reference tables with keys, but the `product` table seems to be storing strings instead of ids.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty hmm seems good idea for search, but how to print cities names, do I need to create a new query inside query?

Comment: @Elona use join to show the city name and same for category name

Comment: @Elona seems you have a typo here.see the answer

Comment: You need to join the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need dynamic sql generation check example below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1"; // note default case, always true
if ($category)
    $query .= " AND category = ".intval($category, 10); // note intval
if ($city)
    $query .= " AND city = ".intval($city, 10);
if ($keyword)
    $query .= " AND keyword LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($keyword). "%'"; // note escaping
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

UPDATE: you can use the same approach for queries with JOINS, check this out:

```
$query = "SELECT *
    FROM PRODUCTS
    inner join
    CATEGORIES on (PRODUCTS.category = CATEGORIES.id)
    inner join
    CITIES on (PRODUCTS.city = CITIES.id)
    WHERE 1=1";
```

Comment: aha I understand now this thanks, but can this be like join? to display cities name?

Comment: ah you already posted the answer! +1 deleting mine :) its same

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo here.Add `$` sign to the city variable.This should be the fault you are not getting any results

```
$city = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['city']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$keyword = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z]#', '', mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['keyword']));
$city = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['city']));
$category = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['category']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '$category' OR city = '$city' OR keyword LIKE '%$keyword%'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$category = $row['category'];
$city = $row['city'];
}
?>
```